# Tractatus differences

Tags: wittgenstein

Wittgenstein's Tractatus was first published in 1921 and then republished, with an English translation, in 1922. A second edition came out in the early 1930s with a few differences from the first.  What were the differences between the first and second editions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Ludwig Wittgenstein: *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus*, Side-by-Side-by-Side Edition](https://people.umass.edu/klement/tlp/):

> "For information on changes between the 1922 and 1933 versions of the Ogden translation see [Casimir Lewy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_Lewy), “A Note on the Text of the Tractatus”, [Mind 76 (1967): 416–423](https://www.gwern.net/docs/philo/1967-lewy.pdf)."